# How do dragons communicate?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, communication, dragons

Dragons are giant intelligent monitor lizards. They are intelligent enough to communicate in a human-like manner. They can hiss, but can't make anymore complex sounds. They are also quadrupedal, and too heavy to stand on their hindlegs alone. How could they communicate?

Comment: "Intelligent enough to communicate". That doesnt really tell much unless you specify how complex this communication is meant to be or otherwise explain their intelligence. If you consider communication to be that one individual (the signaler) sends information to another individual (the receiver), and the receiver modifies its behavior in response to the information it received, then it is not a very high bar to clear. There's a crucial difference in whether you want your dragons to attract mates and threaten rivals or discuss philosophy.

Comment: Related: [What exactly would a talking dragon's voice sound like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137149/what-exactly-would-a-talking-dragons-voice-sound-like).

Comment: I saw one say "FUS RO DAH" in a video game once.

Comment: [Speaking, reading, and writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temeraire_(series)), of course. ;)

Comment: Smoke signals, of course.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Smell and rumble**

Lizards are known to communicate with smells. Although this is probably not as sophisticated for normal lizards, it has great potential. Smell is incredibly complex in both production and the smelling. If this can be controlled to a great degree, the communication can give both a wide range of emotions as well as complex language. Like sound, it fades over distance, but more susceptible to wind. Also the message becomes more garbled the further it goes, but emotion likely stays in tact. Furthermore they can leave messages for others at places, much like a dog peeing. Rubbing off some smells at a common place can be enough to convey messages over longer periods of time.

Another is rumbling. Elephants use a deep rumble to communicate over large distances, which these big lizards are also likely to do. The complexity can be done via very subtly changing the sounds of the rumble.

Comment: Crocodiles rumble to communicate through the water too.

Comment: _Smell_ as in _hormone and pheromone_ signals?

Comment: The "rumble" part gave me an idea that our modern factories (where machinery tends to produce low-frequency tones on scale of single Hertz and below) might mess with dragons' communication, perhaps provoking them.

Comment: I tried to point out some consequences and downsides of using smell as a primary form of communications in my answer below.

Comment: I have heard that dinosaurs could have made a variety of rumbling noises, as well as more unusual noises like "honking" by way of cavities in the skull. Sound is just vibration, so all you need for interesting sounds is an interesting body cavity or organ that can be vibrated. Consider that the human larynx is just a very special organ that can be vibrated in a very controlled fashion.

Answer (score 10):

### Telepathy

I mean, I hate to leave what's essentially a one-word answer, but it pretty much speaks for itself.  You might say "But telepathy isn't real".  Well, neither are dragons.  And you'd hardly be the first writer to make telepathic dragons, it's almost a trope, it's so common.

Answer (score 4):

**Facial gestures.**

Dragons are often portrayed with frills, spines, jowls, and other protrusions on their heads for no readily apparent reason. Many animals use their headgear - ears, whiskers, and the like - to communicate; cats and dogs are well-known for their expressive ears, for instance. (Of course, cats and dogs are also known for using their tails. Guess what else dragons also prominently have?)

Facial and body language would allow dragons to have a means of expression that doesn't rely on breathing, so it's more reliable while flying or belching fire on attacking knights or what have you.

Comment: Dragons, due to their size and lifestyle as apex predators are likely to be quite solitary creatures for most of the time, meaning I'd imagine the sentiment I'd imagine they'd want to express most commonly would be "stay away!", which by the time you're having to express via facial gesture has already failed as a message.

Comment: @TomO'Daighre If that's the *only* message they need, then they don't need any language at all, just breathe fire on the interlopers until they either go away or die. But even if that's most of their communication, it may be useful on occasion to have other options.

Answer (score 4):

**Smoke signals**

The archetypal Western dragon is naturally able to breathe fire, so a useful byproduct in this case is smoke. The same muscles that enable the dragon to control its propulsion of fire(or a flaming something) out of its body would also allow it to control the attributes of the resultant smoke. It may prove inconvenient to have to incinerate something in the vicinity every time a dragon has to "talk", so it's likely dragons have adapted to hold the flaming whatever within its body while expelling controlled bursts of smoke through its nostrils or whatever other orifices are available.

Answer (score 3):

**They don't need to.**

Larger animals need more food. The larger a species, the lower its population density can be based on resources. This is especially true for predators, since [around 90 percent of the energy is lost at each step](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/encyclopedia/energy-transfer-ecosystems/#:%7E:text=At%20each%20step%20up%20the,energy%20is%20lost%20as%20heat.) in a food chain. The population of a large predatory species such as a dragon will necessarily be much smaller than the population of its prey.

A lone dragon is probably capable of killing anything it needs to without assistance from another dragon, and is dangerous enough that it is probably an apex predator with nothing to fear from other species. Dragons don't need to live together with other dragons. Reptiles in general tend to be solitary, or not work together when gathered in one place. For example, vipers may sleep in large groups to conserve heat, but no communication is required.

So the question becomes, "Why do dragons need to communicate?"

If they need to mark their territory to prevent encroachment from other dragons, their options may include scratching trees (like bears) or scent marking (like cats). Lizards will use bright colors to signal that they are looking for mates.

[Reptiles are not social animals](https://www.petplace.com/article/reptiles/general/can-reptiles-be-social/), so they have no need to have developed a complex mode of communication, or even enough intelligence to support it.

[Zach Weinersmith explains the issue succinctly](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/sad-truths-mythical-creature-edition).

Comment: you don't have to be a social animal to know how to communicate, I was born antisocial and with a love for solitary time and hatred for being with other people...(I don't hate people, I hate being around them) yet I  can speak.

Comment: If you are human, then you probably derive massive benefits from communication.

Humans used to have natural predators, but the invention of the spear changed that. Humans aren't born knowing how to build a spear, though. They have to be taught by other humans.

Comment: They also aren't born knowing how to read or write, perform math, drive cars, build computers, use a microwave or stove, wear shoes, plant crops, create vaccines, or avoid crocodiles.

If you live in a house, if you have ever had surgery, if you have eaten food that was not scavenged from the wilderness, and if you haven't died from polio, you have benefitted from being a social animal.

Comment: right but you forgot two things, first that nothing of what you mentioned is strictly necessary for survival... you don't need a spear if you can run faster, and building bigger glutes and stronger tendons for more speed is easier than building bigger brains. Survival didn't drive human intelligence but social interaction did, human sex is also 100% communication based.

Comment: and second, is that one human started chipping a rock and told... showed* (they didn't have language) others how to do it, if it weren't for that one person we'd be way behind in technology. all you need is one curious dragon.

Comment: "No need" and "no ability" are different things. While not being social animals, reptiles do have multiple modes of communication, including certain vocalizing species.

Comment: even scorpions teach their children how to hunt, step by step... it is a long and complex schooling system... yet their brains are abysmally small and primitive, and they have no language.

Comment: oops, forgot... let's not forget that another reason humans didn't evolve intelligence for survival is that big heads hinder child birth by giving a massive chance to kill both the child and the mother at once... not the best survival system.  A human who was simply better at running away or climbing away or hiding would have outcompeted smarter humans both because it is easier to evolve and easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

Infrasound transmitted via the ground, using their feet as sender/receiver.

This additionally allows them to have an overview of their surrounding without having to rely on sight.

If I remember correctly, elephants use something similar.

Comment: wouldn't it only work if they are standing on something that has hollow beneath? like the difference between holding your ear against a boulder and holding your ear against a door....

Comment: You don't need any hollow, @Green. See p and s waves from earthquakes, and seismolocation in general.

Comment: @green sound can actually travel through any material solids just don’t really want to move in a wave.

Answer (score 1):

By dancing.

Dragons tend to be pretty solitary animals. They rarely have a need to communicate with each other aside from to discuss  territorial disputes and to impress mates. In both of these situations being having enough energy to preform complex dance moves is beneficial both to intimidate and impress.

It isn’t exactly a language however it doesn’t have words and it works more like interpretive dance the dragons use metaphor and symbolism to convey their messages.

It also lends it self pretty well to something like a writing system — it’s a long held tradition for dragons to  meticulously prepare a large flat pad of soft mud by carrying mouth fulls of water to a suitable area and using their legs to spread the mud into one flat layer. During their dances the dragons will leave behind a distinctive pattern of foot prints that after being dried with a little fire breath forms a record of the interaction. Most dragon layers are surrounded with these patterns recording contracts, mates, and even poetry and stories.

Many dragons even have taken to going on tours of various territories every few centuries read the mud flats and watch whatever dance moves the dragons have been practicing. This while risky for dragons has created a boom in dragon art and poetry.

Answer (score 1):

### Odours - Consequences

This was meant a s comment to @Trioxidane answer but go too long:

Odours as the primary form of communication form has several "disadvantages":

- Producing different pheromones/hormones is hard and need genetic requirements. Even then, it's hard to convey complex information. I'd say to estimate how many odours they'd need to be able to produce to mimic human-like communication is similar to the number of Chinese characters or to Egypt hieroglyphs: About 5,000-10,000. For comparison: The human body emits ~100 hormones.
- Based on the previous point, producing odours is given by their genetics. If they don't interact regularly and update their vocabulary (like humans did in history), they won't be very innovative in their language. This means they will probably only be able to communicate "natural" information: "Fear", "Anger", "Happiness" rather than "What is the meaning of life?".
- Depending on how fast they can emit different odours and how fast they can smell it  sets how fast they can communicate. Realistically this is a rather slow process compared to communicating via sound as the required mechanisms to produce odours is of chemical nature, compared to sound (mechanical). The odours need to be very complex or communications will need much longer via odours than via sound.
- The speed of particles in air is much much smaller than the speed of sound (~10cm/s compared to 330m/s). This means they need to come close to each other to communicate or will have a long delay when talking to each other. Also they would need to wait until the odours diffuse away before continuing the discussion, which introduces another delay in their communication.
- Odours are not suited to communicate over long distances, or only when using wind and emitting a LOT of hormones/pheromones. Using wind means it is a one way communication method.
- Communicating with different participates is hard when all the smells mix. Communication will need to take place in very small groups.

All points that somehow fit to dragons. Considering the above points a communication using odours would look like this: One dragon attracts another dragon either via sound or by some other means. The two dragons then gather very close somewhere, one dragon emits a very complex odour conveying natural information like "Fear". They wait 10 minutes until the smell is gone and the air is pure again, which is necessary to not mix the very complex odors needed to have complex communication. Then the other dragon emits "Surprise", asking why the other dragon has fear. They wait again, and so on. Depended on how often every part needs to say something, I'd estimate this discussion would take ~100-1000 times longer than a comparable human communication.